# Why does kivy TextInput print the same number over again?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to get the total of my TextInput when I press a button.

```
class Streak():
    def __init__(self, action, action_num, day, hour, minute):
        self.action = action
        self.action_num = action_num
        self.day = day
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
```

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self): # build() returns an instance
        return presentation

    def create(self):
        obj = self.root.get_screen('one')
        self.streak = Streak(obj.ids.action_entry.text, obj.ids.streak_entry.text,
                            obj.ids.day_entry.text, obj.ids.hour_entry.text,
                            obj.ids.minute_entry.text)

        total = ((self.streak.day * 86400) + (self.streak.hour * 3600) +
                (self.streak.minute * 60)) # convert into seconds

        print(total)
```

here is the .kv code:

```
        GridLayout:
            cols:3
            rows:2
            Label:
                text: "Day(s)"
                size_hint: None, None
                font_size: 18
            Label:
                text: "Hour(s)"
                size_hint: None, None
                font_size: 18
            Label:
                text: "Minute(s)"
                size_hint: None, None
                font_size: 18
            TextInput:
                id: day_entry
                input_filter: "int"
                multiline: False
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 28
            TextInput:
                id: hour_entry
                input_filter: "int"
                multiline: False
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 28
            TextInput:
                id: minute_entry
                input_filter: "int"
                multiline: False
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 200, 28
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "right"
        anchor_y: "bottom"
        Button:
            text: "Add"
            size: 50, 25
            size_hint: None, None
            font_size: 18
            on_press: app.create()
```

when I input the numbers into the TextInput and press "add" button the program freezes for a little then prints the "day" input many times ex:

days: 1, hours: 0, minutes: 1

console: 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111...

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you never convert the textinput contents to an int - even though only numeric characters are being allowed to be entered, the text itself is still a string.

That means your output is `"1" * 86400 + ...`, which is the larger number of ones you see.

To fix it, you can do something like `self.day = int(day)` in each case.